# Finding if a signal is periodic

Tags: discrete-signals, periodic

Hello I just started learning Signals and Systems and I have a question regarding periodic signals.

For instance:
$x(t) = \cos(3.2t) + \sin(1.6t) + e ^{j2.8t}$ is periodic because of the HCF of the frequencies.($0.4$ rad/s)

and $x(t) = \cos(4t) + \sin(\pi t)$ isn't because of there is no common factors between $4$ and $\pi$.

But what about this:
$x(t) = 6 \sin (12 \pi t) + 4 e ^{ j (8 \pi  t + \pi /4)} + 2$

How do I determine whether it is period and its fundamental frequency?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20074/fundamental-frequency/20079#20079) to a related question should also answer your question.

Comment: hey, just do the same thing you did before.  looks like all of the frequency terms have a $\pi$ factor in there.  see what's left when you factor $\pi$  out.

Comment: see [MUSIC algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_signal_classification) and [pitch detetcion algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm)

Comment: What got me confused was that the model answer determined the fundamental frequency as HCF of {6, 4 } which is 2. Which in this case is the co-efficient of the signals. Why is this so here?